# Python-Eve: formatting GET response to HTTP 200

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I have `Python-Eve` running with `MongoDB` on a `Ubuntu VM`. I am trying to write an api to handle POST requests from an Iridium [RockBLOCK](http://www.rock7mobile.com/products-rockblock) modem. I have tested the API with `Chrome Postman`, and am able to successfully POST data.

When I try and send messages from my `RockBLOCK` I get 422 error messages on the VM. I am pretty sure this is because the `RockBLOCK` is not able to handle `XML` or `JSON` data, and is set up to simply look for an `HTTP 200` response.

So how would I setup eve to respond with solely `HTTP 200` when the POST request is received?

[API Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSndl.png) taken from RockBLOCK Web Services Guide.

Comment: Maybe you can use [Event hooks](http://python-eve.org/features.html#eventhooks) in order to modify the status code as desired. However, I am not sure about this since I am a beginner using eve.

Comment: I think you are correct, the on_inserted event hook seems to be what I am looking for. Still not sure on how to get rid of the JSON data in the response.

Comment: You might print `response.json` in order to get the response json-formatted (Python dictionary). By doing this, you might be able to somehow filter the response content by removing unneeded or copying the desired keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `422` is returned from Eve when a validation error occurs. I would look into your request payload and make sure it adheres to validation rules. A typical example of a response like this would be when you have a `unique` rule for a field, and a POST comes in with an already used value for that field.

> So how would I setup eve to respond with solely HTTP 200 when the POST request is received?

Right now you can disable either JSON or XML responses by respectively setting `JSON = False` or `XML = False`, but not both. Since Eve is a Flask application you could look into changing the response on the flight but again, given the error you are getting I don't think that is the problem  you are facing right now.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up switching to plain flask to finish the development, since the RockBlock could not handle XML or JSON. Really enjoyed eve and will be looking to use it in future projects!